# facebook sdk ios get user information

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `facebook sdk 3.0`, however I'm facing difficulties when I'm trying to get user's information like email etc.

**My Code:**

```
- (IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender {

    [self facebookLogin];
}

-(void) facebookLogin
{

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
   allowLoginUI:YES
completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
  switch (state) {
      case FBSessionStateOpen:
          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
              if (error) {
              }
              else {
                  name = [FBuser name];
                  email = [FBuser objectForKey:@"email"];
                  pic = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [FBuser objectID]];  
              }
          }];
          [self checkUser];
          break;
  }
}];
}
```

My code opens the Facebook login, and ask for authorisation but after that It returns to my app showing/geting nothing with that.
I diagnose through break points and found that after the line `switch (state)` it simply exits without giving any information.

My Question is, how can I fetch user's email via `facebook sdk 3.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add the below to app delegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
        return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

}
```

don't forget to import the header:

```
#import "FacebookSDK.h"
```

Comment: `if (status == FBSessionStateOpen) ` after this breakpoint, the thread exit.

Comment: can you check if you have a valid session? and tell me what you got! I will edit my answer to add the method which check for a valid session!
Or what is the status you got?

Comment: let me check and acknowledge you.

Comment: `if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)` after this check, the breakpoint returns.

Comment: do you handle the callback in the app delegate??

Comment: No, I've not put anything regarding FB Login in app delegate.

Comment: okay I'll edit my answer, make the changes and tell me if it worked.

Comment: @developer why the answer isn't checked as correct! check it so others can find out the it's the correct answer man!